# download and run PHP on a NAS drive?

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface, nas

I have a NAS drive for receiving files and also I have a script prepared in PHP which can push those files on to the BOX. Now my question is - can I use the same NAS drive to run the script by downloading PHP CLI on the NAS?.

Please let me know if it is possible. NAS is Linux drive.

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Comment: all I have is - a NAS drive attached to a server. and a PHP script which uses BOX access token to upload files to BOX.